# How to load background image in sprite class in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx, sprites

How can I insert a background image in sprite class?
here is my code..Thank's and advance

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;



public class Sprite implements ApplicationListener {
// Constant rows and columns of the sprite sheet
private static final int FRAME_COLS = 5, FRAME_ROWS = 1;
// Objects used
Animation<TextureRegion> walkAnimation; // Must declare frame type (TextureRegion)
Texture walkSheet;
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

// A variable for tracking elapsed time for the animation
float stateTime;

@Override
public void create() {
    // Load the sprite sheet as a
    walkSheet = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("cat2.png"));
    // Use the split utility method to create a 2D array of TextureRegions. This is
    // possible because this sprite sheet contains frames of equal size and they are
    // all aligned.
    TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(walkSheet,
            walkSheet.getWidth() / FRAME_COLS,
            walkSheet.getHeight() / FRAME_ROWS);

    // Place the regions into a 1D array in the correct order, starting from the top
    // left, going across first. The Animation constructor requires a 1D array.

    TextureRegion[] walkFrames = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS * FRAME_ROWS];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS; j++) {
            walkFrames[index++] = tmp[i][j];
        }
    }
    // Initialize the Animation with the frame interval and array of frames
    walkAnimation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.075f, walkFrames);

    // Instantiate a SpriteBatch for drawing and reset the elapsed animation
    // time to 0
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    stateTime = 0f;
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}
@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear screen
    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); // Accumulate elapsed animation time

    // Get current frame of animation for the current stateTime
    TextureRegion currentFrame = walkAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
    spriteBatch.begin();
    spriteBatch.draw(currentFrame, 50, 50); // Draw current frame at (50, 50)
    spriteBatch.end();


}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() { // SpriteBatches and Textures must always be disposed
    spriteBatch.dispose();
    walkSheet.dispose();
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I think you should go read the libgdx wiki:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki

To answer your question, just create a Texture with the background image and then draw it. I have written it below this text and i have inserted it in your code and marked it with bold.

```
Texture Background;
Background = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Background.png"));
spriteBatch.draw(Background,0,0);
Background.dispose();
```

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;





public class Sprite implements ApplicationListener {
// Constant rows and columns of the sprite sheet
private static final int FRAME_COLS = 5, FRAME_ROWS = 1;
// Objects used
Animation walkAnimation; // Must declare frame type (TextureRegion)
Texture walkSheet;
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
Texture Background;

// A variable for tracking elapsed time for the animation
float stateTime;

@Override
public void create() {
    // Load the sprite sheet as a
    walkSheet = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("cat2.png"));
    // Use the split utility method to create a 2D array of TextureRegions. This is
    // possible because this sprite sheet contains frames of equal size and they are
    // all aligned.
    TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(walkSheet,
            walkSheet.getWidth() / FRAME_COLS,
            walkSheet.getHeight() / FRAME_ROWS);

    // Place the regions into a 1D array in the correct order, starting from the top
    // left, going across first. The Animation constructor requires a 1D array.

    TextureRegion[] walkFrames = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS * FRAME_ROWS];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i (0.075f, walkFrames);

    // Instantiate a SpriteBatch for drawing and reset the elapsed animation
    // time to 0
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    stateTime = 0f;

    Background = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Background.png")); //File from assets folder
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}
@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear screen
    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); // Accumulate elapsed animation time

    // Get current frame of animation for the current stateTime
    TextureRegion currentFrame = walkAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
    spriteBatch.begin();
    spriteBatch.draw(Background,0,0);
    spriteBatch.draw(currentFrame, 50, 50); // Draw current frame at (50, 50)
    spriteBatch.end();


}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() { // SpriteBatches and Textures must always be disposed
    spriteBatch.dispose();
    walkSheet.dispose();
    Background.dispose();
}


}
```

Comment: Thank's to Klemmensen, in addition, if you implements Screen use game.batch.draw(Background,0,0);